# laravel BadMethodCall() error while caliing for index in api

Tags: php, laravel

the Ptag controller

```
    <?php

      namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Validator;
    use App\Ptag;
    use App\Http\Resources\PtagResource;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


    class PtagController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request){
            $query=Ptag::query();
    return PtagResource::collection($query);
     }
    }
```

ptag resource

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Resources;

    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

    class PtagResource extends JsonResource
    {
        /**
        * Transform the resource into an array.
         *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return array
        */
       public function toArray($request)
       {
           return [
           'id'=>$this->id,
           'title'=>$this->title
        // 'product'=>$this->product()
            ];
        }
      }
```

ptag model

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Ptag extends Model
    {
        protected $guarded=[];

         public function product(){
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
     }
   }
```

error is shown as such

> ErrorException: array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead in file /home/rajesh/project/handicom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php on line 53

Comment: Check the version of PHP you are using, and compare it to the minimum requirements for your version of laravel.

Comment: i have php -v of 7.4 and laravel requires minimum php -v of 6.3. that checks out

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel -v of 5.7

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

---

In `DelegatesToResource.php` file of `vendor` folder, we have the following code:

```
public function offsetExists($offset)
{
    return array_key_exists($offset, $this->resource);
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php

`array_key_exists` function is deprecated on PHP `7.4.x`. So, the error you met is related to PHP, not Laravel.

**Solution:**

---

**Method 1:** The easiest way is to downgrade your PHP version. Naturally, you still have to ensure the [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#server-requirements) of Laravel `5.7` (PHP >=7.1.3)

**Method 2:** You upgrade your project to higher version. To limit too many changes in your project, you could use version `5.8`. In this version, the library no longer uses `array_key_exists` function.

```
public function offsetExists($offset)
{
    return isset($this->resource[$offset]);
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php